# How prevent indexing of contents of a page, not the page itself?

Tags: seo

How can I make front-page and category pages of my CMS being indexed just by their meta description tag not by their contents (posts, navigation, ...)?

**edit:** Contents on these pages are generated dynamically and change frequently, so I want to prevent users don't find what they saw in search result summary

**edit:** Can `nosnippet` help for this or does it prevent the display of meta description content too?

Also How I can prevent indexing of contents of particular tag in a page?

Comment: Search engines nowadays don’t give much about a meta description. (And why should they? As a user, I’m doing a search for content that is readable to me when I open the page the search engine points me to – I don’t want to find pages based on a meta description that I can’t even see, that would be useless.) As for the second question, see [googleoff/googleon tags](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/46/admin_crawl/Preparing?hl=de&csw=1#pagepart) – AFAIK(!) other major search engines adhere to these “tags” invented by Google now as well.

Comment: looks like googleoff and googleon tags are specific to the google appliance.

Comment: @CBroe contents on these pages are generated dynamically and change frequently, so I want to prevent users don't find what they saw in search result summary

Comment: Well then don’t have SEs index those pages at all. You surely will have some kind of permanent URL under which the individual pieces of content will be available for longer? Then let them index those - `noindex,follow` on the pages with the frequently changing content, and full indexing for the individual article pages.

Answer (score 0):

Add this between your head tags:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
```

But, Yandex does not care about this which is not respectful.

Comment: Checking if its front page or category page is another question I think, as we don't know his CMS.

Comment: On a side note Baidu definitely looks at meta keywords tags. Also look into setting up web master tools for Baidu.